# xcode and bitbucket

Tags: xcode, bitbucket

When I try to add my repo to xcode organizer, I get the following:

[image]

I googled this and searched here and found nothing...wth

Comment: What's the URL you're trying to connect to with Xcode? The SSH or the HTTPS one?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the App SourceTree to manage bitbucket and github projects. You can download it from mac app store for free.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up doing it manually through terminal for the first time per bitbucket instructions and now it allows me to do it all through the xcode interface.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with hg(mercurial) on bitbucket.org, you can reference this url:http://tadabborat.tumblr.com/post/9502320721/mercurial-warning-bitbucket-org-certificate-with
I solve my issues by following the guide.
If you add the publickey information, you can use bitbucket.org smoothly.